# What is the probability distribution for the number of trials between successes?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am a bit of a novice at statistics, so please forgive me for sounding dumb.  I was looking for a probability distribution describing the distribution of the number of trials between successes.  I *think* the Exponential distribution (or maybe Geometric distribution)  satisfies this, but it seems rather counter-intuitive to me.

Lets say I'm playing a lottery where I draw 6 balls from a set of 54, and I want to keep track of how many drawings occur before the number "3" comes up.  My intuition tells me the graph would look like some kind of lop-sided bell curve centered around the number "9" (i.e., 6 in 54 chance, so any given number should occur on average roughly every 9 drawings give or take).

However, if I'm reading things right, the real distribution is exponential, indicating that the number "3" is most likely to occur again only 1 drawing after its previous occurrence and the chance of it occurring again diminishes exponentially with each subsequent failure.

My (probably wrong) math seems to support this:
Let S = likelihood of successfully drawing a "3" in one trial = 6/54 = 1/9.
Let F = likelihood of failing to draw a "3" in one trial = 48/54 = 8/9.
Let x = the number of trials before a "3" occurs.
Then (I think), P(x) = F <sup>x-1</sup> × S = (8/9)<sup>x-1</sup> × (1/9).

But since all of that sort of violates my intuition, I am wondering if I am wrong, or if I am thinking of the problem in the wrong way or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the probability of a success on the first trial is $p$, and the trials are independent (which they should be for a lottery), then the probability of $n-1$ failures followed by a success is $p(1-p)^{n-1}$, which does decay exponentially.

Comment: Thank you Angela.  Your answer at least validates that my math is correct, even if the answer violates my intuition hehe.  Its like saying that a man who has a 10% chance of living in any given year will statistically live forever if he fails to die for long enough...I just don't get it.

Comment: It is not "like saying" what you say, at all. What makes you think it is?

Comment: I was discounting the aging process of course, but if I said 'p' is the probability of dying in any given year of one's life = 5%, then failure to die is 1 - p = 95%, right?  As such, p(n=1) < p(n=10) < p(50).  In effect, the longer one lives, the less chance they have of dying.  It just seems like there should be a different non-exponential distribution for things that we know *will* occur, but the number of trials it takes for them to occur is variable.

Comment: Exponential (in this case, geometric) distributions model exactly this: "things that we know will occur, but the number of trials it takes for them to occur is variable."